# Is it safe to share bitcoin address and signature generated from electrum wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address, electrum, signature

Some bitcoin airdrops are asking to prove ownership on bitcoin address by sharing signature.

My question is if one shares bitcoin address and signature is there any risk of a attacker to compute the private key with this knowledge.

Note I am using electrum wallet to generate the signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is if one shares bitcoin address and signature is there any risk of a attacker to compute the private key with this knowledge

While signing, the public key becomes exposed. The primary assumption is "It's impossible to find the private key which relates to a known public key", and this assumption isn't likely to be disproved (in other words, cracked) in the next 10 years.

The process of signing a message to claim airdrops is absolutely safe, as you can move your coins to a different address after claiming your airdrops.

The only risk is your privacy: They'll know how much money you have. If that's an issue, you can just mix your coins after you're done.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to get the private key from a signature.

But someone (person B) could force you to sign a special message so that person B can pretend to person C to own that amount of bitcoins.